# How to save dynamically added checkbox value in localStorage?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I want to save my checkbox value dynamically. When i check a specific one , all checkboxes are checked.Used target  but did not work. Any ideas?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq0w7w9j/)

```js
 var data = localStorage.getItem("checkbox");
    if (data) {
       $("input[name='checkbox-name']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
    
  $(document).on('change', "input[name='checkbox-name']", function (e) {
     var target = $(e.target );
    if (target.is(":checked")) {
        localStorage.setItem("checkbox", 1);
    } else {
         localStorage.removeItem("checkbox");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are your checkboxes have different names? You are only saving "checkbox" 1 to local storage not any identifiers.

Comment: No , checkboxes have only id and name.Used names cos id's are unique @CanCelik

Comment: You need to save the status of checkboxes with those unique IDs so you can get the right ones.

Comment: already did but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal is based on removing the IDs and avoiding to save the checkboxes state separately:

I updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq0w7w9j/1/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  parent.remove();

  var list = $("#list").html();
  localStorage.setItem("list", list);
  return false;
});

$(document).on('change', "input[name='checkbox-name']", function (e) {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  } else {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
  }
  var list = $("#list").html();
  localStorage.setItem("list", list);
});

$(function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem('list')) {
    $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
  }

  $("#add").click(function () {
    var userList = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
    var newitem = '<p>' + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-name"/> ' + userList + '<input type="submit" value="X" class="delete"/></p>';
    $('#list').append(newitem);

    var list = $("#list").html();
    localStorage.setItem('list', list);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="textarea" placeholder="Write here..."/>
<button id="add">Add</button>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Actually i tried same as you do but  my code did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Save your checkboxes with their unique IDs.

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
     var checkboxId = $(this).attr('id');
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       localStorage.setItem(checkboxId, 1);
     } else {
       localStorage.removeItem(checkboxId);
     }
});
```

Then you can retrieve it:

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var value = localStorage[key];
    if (value == 1) {
      $('#' + key).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
}
```

Here is JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hc09LpfL/2/

Regardless of whether you create your checkboxes dynamically or manually they all have ids.

In your fiddle, this is the code that generates the checkboxes. I guess you don't understand this part as you are assigning the same id and name for all of them.

```
var newitem = '<p>' + '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-name" id="checkbox"/> ' + userList + '<input type="submit" value="X" id="delete"  class="delete"/></p>';
```

Comment: In you JSFiddle all checkboxes have the same id. I just updated my code and include a JSFiddle for you. It works!

Comment: Yea thanks this works but i am adding checkboxes dynamically, so wont work on me

Comment: Why it wouldn't work? You just need to give different Ids to checkboxes instead of giving them the same ID.